# How to parametrize $\left(4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 +z^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

How would I parametrize $$\left(4-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 +z^2=1$$

I am really struggling to parametrize this surface.

Here is what I observed the surface is $$(4-r)^2+z^2=1$$ so perhaps we can try and use some kind of polar coordinates to parametrize the surface that would normally involve getting a surface of the form $r=f(\theta,z)$.

But I really don't know how to proceed with this one.

Any help?

Comment: The parameterization you use usually depends on what you need to do with it.  What do you need to do with the parameterization here?  Also, it can be parameterized pretty nicely in cylindrical coordinates, which you've essentially already done.

Comment: Using it to take a surface integral.

Comment: Could you explain how to parametrize this from where I am?

Comment: I'd need to see the entire problem.  For instance, are you taking the surface integral over the entire thing between $z=a$ and $z=b$, or is this surface intersecting a tilted plane, etc.

Comment: Well at first I just need to find a parameterization for the surface. If it helps the answer given is $((4+\cos (a))\cos b),(4+\cos (a))\sin b), \sin b)$

Comment: I think the $z$-coordinate should be $\sin a$.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Based on our comment discussion, I would proceed as follows.  Our surface is given by the equation
$$ \left(4 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 + z^2 = 1. $$

Note that we have a thing squared plus a thing squared equals 1.  This reminds me of $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$.  So, I'd like to parameterize so that I get something like
$$ \underbrace{\left(4 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}_{\cos^2\theta} + \underbrace{z^2}_{\sin^2\theta} = 1. $$

Well, parameterizing $z$ is easy.  Just let $z = \sin \theta$.  A little more work is required for $x$ and $y$.  So far for $x$ and $y$ all we have is $ 4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \cos\theta$.  We can rewrite this as
$$4 - \cos\theta = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$$

Thinking in terms of polar coordinates as you were, if $x = r\cos\phi$ and $y = r\sin\phi$, then $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = r$.  Note that I am ignoring issues about positive vs. negative square roots here.  Anyway, in our case we clearly want $r = 4 - \cos\theta$.  This therefore gives us $x = (4-\cos\theta)\cos\phi$ and $y = (4-\cos\theta)\sin\phi$.

So the final parameterization is:
$$ (x,y,z) = \big((4-\cos\theta)\cos\phi, \ (4-\cos\theta)\sin\phi, \ \sin\theta\big)$$

Note that this is different from the provided answer you mentioned, but both parameterizations are correct (except for the $z$-coordinate being $\sin b$ -- I still maintain that the $z$-coordinate is supposed to be $\sin a$ in the answer you mentioned).  You can verify them both by plugging them into the equation.  I believe they have $4+$ where I have $4-$ because where I said
$$ \left(4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 = \cos^2\theta \Rightarrow
  4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \cos\theta, $$
they said
$$ \left(4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2 = \cos^2\theta \Rightarrow
  4 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = -\cos\theta. $$

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.- My intention is to highlight the kind of your curve whose parameterization with spherical coordinates has been already given.
Your equation is clearly equivalent to $$15+x^2+y^2+z^2=8\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
patent of which is that your curve is a quadric.

The quite interesting (*at least for me*) is that this quadric must be (birrationally) equivalent to an elliptic curve because of the graphic below which shows a torus with a hole, so of genus $1$, and rotational symmetry about the z-axis (*see at the figure below two photos of this beauty*).

In the case of a single-holed torus, (*i.e. of genus $1$ and there are torus of genus $g>1$ which have $g$ holes*) as ours,  are well known both the cartesian and the parametric equations.
$$(c-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^2+z^2= r^2$$ where $c$ and $r$ are the center of the hole and its radius respectively. Furthermore the parametric are
$$\begin{cases}x=(c+r\cos \theta)\cos \phi\\y=(c+r\cos \theta)\sin \phi \\z=r\sin \theta\\ \phi, \theta\in[0,2\pi[\end{cases}$$
You can see clearly that your equation corresponds to a particular case of this general fact.

[image]